# How do you know if multivaribale limit exists or not? Is there any technique for determining it besides from the usual epsilon - delta definition.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have recently started doing multivariable limits for my multivariable Calculus Course of College. However I am struggling in determining whether the particular limit exists or not.

I have been taught to determine it using $y = mx$, $y = mx^{2}$ , $y = m^{2}x^{2}$, but in case when I don't know which form to use, I just use hit and trial to determine if the equation is homogenous.

This however fails if the limit actually exists, while I mindlessly attempt to prove it does not, by continuing to substitute such parameters.

My question is, that whether there is any equation through which we can determine if the function actually is homgenous or can be changed to homogenous function
(Ex:- $y = x - mx^{3}$)

Is there any objective and fast way to just see if the equation can be changed to homogenous equation?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).